# Using Flash components into Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flash

**What is the right way for integrating a Flash component into a Flex application?**

I heard that there are different ways of integration between Flash and Flex: using SWF, using SWC (something else?). What are theirs pros and cons?

What are the points of communication between them Flash and Flex?

*I'm using Flash Builder 4 for developing Flex. And Flash Professional CS 5 for developing Flash.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I use flash (professional) to develop customized graphics and movieClips. I turn those into Flex Components (by having them extend mx.flash.UIMovieClip) and export a SWC file.  Each element in my flash (professional) library that has an instance name is now available to Flex in that SWC (after I put the SWC in the /lib directory of my project).

I'm considering moving over to FlashCatalyst for this kind of stuff and reserving Flash Professional for when I need to do customized animations.

Mainly, because flash is buggy, at times.  Which is not something I would mind as much if it weren't for the fact that flash also does an AWFUL job of displaying error information.  Right now, for example, I'm authoring some flash components and it keeps deleting all my actionscript from the file!  That makes all my movieclip objects play in an infinite loop (because all the stop() calls are deleted!)

It's annoying.